# gem and ruby commands causing `require': cannot load such file -- monitor

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redhat

I am installing ruby on a red hat 7 server.

any commands using gem or ruby, such as `$ gem` or `$ ruby`, produce the following error:

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- monitor (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1107:in `require'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1107:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby several times, as well as finding and removing other versions of ruby (I am currently using 2.0.0).

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing around with system ruby, you can try setting up ruby using a ruby version manager like `rvm` or `rbenv`:

rvm:
https://rvm.io/

rbenv: 
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Comment: I've already tried using rvm. ruby was working just fine last week, but once I started messing around with the version manager I started getting these errors.

Comment: did you make sure that you are running ruby through rvm though? i.e. not system ruby

Comment: rvm is no longer installed on my machine

Comment: can you give detail of what you have done with rvm to produce these errors?

Comment: well, I tried (and failed) to `rvm install 1.8.7` which gave some kind of RHSA error. Then I uninstalled RVM entirely because I decided some other issues I was having were likely not related to ruby versions. However, I am now getting a weird error every time I use `cd`: `-bash: /home/[user]/.rvm: No such file or directory` which is obviously true since RVM is no longer installed.

Comment: sounds like you still have /home/[user]/.rvm in your search path somehow ... what exact step did you do to uninstall rvm? Also, did you run rvm install with sudo authority?

Comment: i did run rvm installl with sudo. also, exiting and restarting the terminal resolved the `bash` error.

Comment: since your error msg stems from ruby not being able to find its required gems, one thing you can try is to find out where these gems are located and export it to the search path: `export PATH=[path_to_gem]:$PATH`

Comment: I haven't actually solved this issue: I just uninstalled ruby completely and started to use JRuby (what I actually need) instead, which is working for the most part. I still have no idea why I was getting those errors. However, I'll mark your answer as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot believe that a suggestion of using a Ruby version manager is accepted as an answer.

The problem you are truly facing is that your Ruby can't open
`/usr/share/ruby/monitor.rb` file. You can confirm this by running `strace ruby -rmonitor -e ''`. So the file is obviously missing.

As this file comes from the `ruby-libs` package on RHEL 7, please reinstall it by running:

```
sudo yum reinstall ruby-libs
```

That's it.